# Is this possible to get categories sorted by RAND()?

Tags: magento, magento-1.6

I want to display product categories in random order.
Is that possible?
How can I achieve this?

I'm using custom theme, and categories are fetch by:

```
    $_categories = $this->getStoreCategories();
```

Maybe it will be easier to use php shuffle function?

Comment: Yes, this is possible. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I didn't tried anything yet. I can't find any solution.

Comment: Are you familiar with Magneto observers? If not then shuffling the results of `getStoreCategories` is definitely a quicker way.

Comment: Unfortunately not. That's my first touch with Magento.

Answer (score 0):

After you have got the collection of the categories, do you want to try using this

```
    $arrCategories->getSelect()->order(new Zend_Db_Expr('RAND()'))->limit('5');
```

I have used this on a different collection of items, so I am not sure if this can work on Categories. But I think its worth trying..It is just writing a select query with Order by RAND().

Hope it works.

Cheers,

Swapna